# Can we tag questions about λ-calculus better?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are some groups of question on the site which are not tagged well, especially outside of "core" TCS (which we have covered pretty well, I think).

One of these are questions about [lambda-calculus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus). Many questions have only the main tag, or maybe tags about other concepts if the question is a comparative one.

Can we tag these questions better? In particular, there are quite some that involve transforming λ-terms into each other; I think these should have their own "technique" tag (similar to [reductions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reductions) which does not quite apply here).

I would ask users knowledgeable in this area to propose a (small) set of tags that can help differentiate the space of λ-calculus questions better. Attempts at generalisation so tags can be used for many calculi (e.g. π-calculus, μ- calculus) are appreciated.

Ideally, suggestions would contain (stubs for) tag wikis, too.

<sub>If you think another area is covered badly by existing tags, please open another meta discussion!</sub>

Answer (score 5):

(I'm not an expert on lambda calculus, but I was taught by one.)

I don't think our questions about lambda calculus are particularly badly tagged.

I've retagged one question which only had the [lambda-calculus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus) tag. The remaining questions which are only tagged [lambda-calculus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus) or only [logic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) [lambda-calculus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus) are about elementary to absolute-beginner considerations of beta-reductions (and sometimes eta-reductions) between lambda terms and encoding of data structures such as Church numerals (with [one exception](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13624/is-there-a-one-point-combinator-which-does-not-apply-any-of-its-arguments-to-an) which I've just closed as unclear).

I don't see much room for more precise tags for the bulk of these questions. Here are candidate tags that could complement [lambda-calculus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus) for which at least one question exists on the site:

- [beta-reduction](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-reduction) strikes me as useless because it's practically synonymous with [lambda-calculus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus).
- [eta-reduction](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eta-reduction) (especially since it can be hard to search for when spelled $\eta$ reduction) for [1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1607/reduction-rule-for-if) [2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14372/equivalence-of-two-lambda-expressions-for-not)
- [church-numerals](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-numerals) for [1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/a-lambda-calculus-evaluation-involving-church-numerals) [2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/representing-negative-and-complex-numbers-using-lambda-calculus) [3](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12779/defining-lambda-expressions) [4](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14133/whats-wrong-with-my-beta-reduction-of-pred-c-0-on-church-encoding)
- [lambda-mu-calculus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-mu-calculus) for [one candidate](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11417/are-there-a-lambda-mu-expression-equivalent-to-the-yin-yang-puzzle), but I think [continuations](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/continuations) suffices.
- [combinators](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinators) in [1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/is-there-a-typed-ski-calculus) [2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9604/clear-intuitive-derivation-of-the-fixed-point-combinator-y-combinator) [3](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13624/is-there-a-one-point-combinator-which-does-not-apply-any-of-its-arguments-to-an) [4](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13901/what-is-the-name-of-this-combinator)

Going in the other direction, some of these very elementary [lambda-calculus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus) questions are really about term rewriting, as they are simply about applying the beta reduction rule. We have a tag for that, or rather two which I've just merged (not sure about the direction): [term-rewriting](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term-rewriting) = [rewriting-systems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewriting-systems). I think this is the “technique” tag that you envision. But these elementary questions are not very interesting to people interested in rewriting systems in general.

I don't see any room for general aspects of rewriting systems that would lead to other tags being applied to any existing [lambda-calculus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus) question.

Incidentally, when I see *reductions*, I always think of rewriting systems first. Using the tag name [reductions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reductions) for the use in complexity and computability theory feels strange to me. Rewriting wouldn't compete for the tag name even if the site didn't have a strong bias towards these fields, as questions about reduction are about [term-rewriting](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term-rewriting).

Comment: What you write makes sense, but I'll let experts be the final judges. Just a few comments: 1) "elementary questions are not very interesting to people interested in rewriting systems in general." -- this case can be made for all general tags, I think, so no harm done. 2) What are you saying with your last paragraph -- should we find a better way for complexity/computability reductions (I don't like the name choice myself as the term is heavily overloaded), or do you think it's fine?

Comment: Come to think of it, what do you think of using [tag:programming-languages] and [tag:functional-programming] on questions about lambda-calculus? I noticed a few instances.

Comment: @Raphael Some of the questions with both [tag:lambda-calculus] and either [tag:programming-languages] or [tag:functional-programming] are about applying lambda calculus to the study of programming languages and thus properly tagged. A couple could lose the FP or PL tag, I'll make a pass. The one that bothers me is [tag:logic], it's used on plenty of questions that have nothing to do with logic except in the sense that all math is applied logic.

Comment: @Raphael While [tag:reductions] is slightly prone to confusion, the rewriting use wouldn't use “reductions” as a tag name, so I think it's ok unless you can think of a more descriptive name (“problem-reductions” would be worse).

Comment: @Raphael I've retagged http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14133/whats-wrong-with-my-beta-reduction-of-pred-c-0-on-church-encoding, the rest warranted the FP or PL tag.

Comment: Regarding reductions, what about [tag:turing-reductions]? As far as I know, that's the most general term in computability and complexity. The logic tag, I may have introduced that a couple of times myself when the question seemed to be about a logic calculus thing. Feel free to retag as you see fit.

Comment: @Raphael I like “Turing reduction”, but isn't that applicable only to computability and not complexity?

Comment: Wikipedia says (and I agree) that the "complexity-reductions" are special cases, i.e. restrictions of what the reduction function may do (they are all computable, which is pretty much the only restriction of Turing reductions). It *may* invoke unwanted associations, that's true.